# How to reuse the same api for Partner Website and custom backoffice SPA?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, microservices

We have some Web API 2 that we are using :
  - internally via a backoffice js SPA 
  - and externally from an external partner website

In order to control authorization we have designed our code with the Authorize attribute :

```
[Route("{me}/Default", Name = "UpdatePersonalAccount")]
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "UpdatePersonalAccount")]
public async Task<string> UpdatePersonalAccount(UserInfo userInfoDTO)
{
    var result = await _dbContextHandler.UsingDbContextAsync(_dbFactory,
        async db => await _userServices.UpdatePersonalAccount(db, userInfoDTO, User));

    var apiResult = result;
    return apiResult;
}
```

In this case for example, the caller need to have the "UpdatePersonalAccount" permission.
The internal admin users are defined in our system and we assicated them a role (ie. group of permission).
When a internal admin user identify himself on a SPA js application we are verifying that he have the required permission at the api level.

Now we intent to expose our api to an external partner website and I am a litlle bit confused about how to do it.
Here how we plan to expose our apis to external website :

[image: planned architecture]

Create a fake service account and set it permission in our internal authorization service seems wrong.
So I want to know what is the more effective or standard way to do it ?

Comment: What service is generating the Access Token - is it yours or external?  Does the Access token contain any authorization claims info?

Comment: The service that is generating the access token is mine. We are used to retrieve the acces token sent by the SPA (a guid) and then internally when asking the authorization service with this access token it  give us back a list of authorization associated with it that we check in our service call.